# Error while using Tensorflow-Hub and Colab TPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu, tensorflow-hub, tpu

I am trying to use BERT for text classification using Tensorflow hub. The code runs fine on Colab GPU but when I converted it for Colab TPU it shows up the following 'uninitialized layer' error.
Following is the Bert Layer-

```
class BertLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
          def __init__(self, n_fine_tune_layers, **kwargs):
              self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
              self.trainable = True
              self.output_size = 768
              super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

          def build(self, input_shape):
              self.bert = hub.Module(
                  bert_path,
                  trainable=True,# did this in place of self.trainable
                  name="{}_module".format(self.name)
              )

              trainable_vars = self.bert.variables


              trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]
              #print("--------------------------len=",len(trainable_vars))
              # Select how many layers to fine tune
              trainable_vars = trainable_vars[-self.n_fine_tune_layers:]

              # Add to trainable weights
              for var in trainable_vars:
                  self._trainable_weights.append(var)

              for var in self.bert.variables:
                  if var not in self._trainable_weights:
                      self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

              super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

          def call(self, inputs):
              inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
              input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
              bert_inputs = dict(
                  input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
              )
              result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
                  "pooled_output"
              ]
              return result

          def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
              return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)
```

Following is my model -

```
print("-----------------------------1")
      from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input,Dense
      #from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
      #Name="test run-{}".format(1)
      #tensorboard=TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(Name))
      in_id=Input(shape=(max_seq_length,),)
      in_mask=Input(shape=(max_seq_length,),)
      in_segment=Input(shape=(max_seq_length,),)
      print("-----------------------------2")
      in_id = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
      in_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
      in_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,))
      print("-----------------------------3")
      bert_inputs=[in_id,in_mask,in_segment]
      bert_outputs=BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=100)(bert_inputs)
      #step=bert_outpu
      step=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(bert_outputs)
      step=tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(step)
      #step=tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu')(step)
      step=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)(step)
      step=tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(step)
      #dense=tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu')(bert_outputs)
      step=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout)(step)
      pred=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(step)
      model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=bert_inputs,outputs=pred)
      print("-----------------------------4")
      model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr),
                    metrics=[f1,'accuracy'])
      print("-----------------------------5")
      tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model,
                                                    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu_address)))

      print("-----------------------------6")
      sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
      K.set_session(sess)
      print("-----------------------------7")
      tpu_model.fit([train_input_ids, train_input_masks, train_segment_ids],
                train_labels,
                epochs=epochs,
                batch_size=64)
                #validation_data=([val_input_ids, val_input_masks, val_segment_ids],val_labels))
      model.evaluate([test_input_ids, test_input_masks, test_segment_ids],test_labels)
```

And follwing is the Error-

```
-----------------------------1
-----------------------------2
-----------------------------3
INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

I0605 10:36:17.033424 140062933383040 saver.py:1483] Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

-----------------------------4
-----------------------------5
INFO:tensorflow:Querying Tensorflow master (grpc://10.85.103.202:8470) for TPU system metadata.

I0605 10:36:17.748405 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:59] Querying Tensorflow master (grpc://10.85.103.202:8470) for TPU system metadata.

INFO:tensorflow:Found TPU system:

I0605 10:36:17.768394 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:120] Found TPU system:

INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores: 8

I0605 10:36:17.770817 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:121] *** Num TPU Cores: 8

INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Workers: 1

I0605 10:36:17.773086 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:122] *** Num TPU Workers: 1

INFO:tensorflow:*** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8

I0605 10:36:17.775260 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:124] *** Num TPU Cores Per Worker: 8

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, -1, 8086897810259541316)

I0605 10:36:17.779561 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, -1, 8086897810259541316)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 8309407237260141527)

I0605 10:36:17.782429 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 8309407237260141527)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 17179869184, 7140089854169573112)

I0605 10:36:17.785550 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:0, TPU, 17179869184, 7140089854169573112)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 17179869184, 17762152438583970348)

I0605 10:36:17.789351 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:1, TPU, 17179869184, 17762152438583970348)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 17179869184, 12631201787268957494)

I0605 10:36:17.793601 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:2, TPU, 17179869184, 12631201787268957494)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 17179869184, 8708359633115695081)

I0605 10:36:17.796261 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:3, TPU, 17179869184, 8708359633115695081)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 17179869184, 601478800410838022)

I0605 10:36:17.800481 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:4, TPU, 17179869184, 601478800410838022)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 17179869184, 16793071921697081555)

I0605 10:36:17.804739 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:5, TPU, 17179869184, 16793071921697081555)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 17179869184, 16730824918382181321)

I0605 10:36:17.807698 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:6, TPU, 17179869184, 16730824918382181321)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 17179869184, 11133990522845180639)

I0605 10:36:17.810022 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU:7, TPU, 17179869184, 11133990522845180639)

INFO:tensorflow:*** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 17179869184, 18001585464951191022)

I0605 10:36:17.812952 140062933383040 tpu_system_metadata.py:126] *** Available Device: _DeviceAttributes(/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:TPU_SYSTEM:0, TPU_SYSTEM, 17179869184, 18001585464951191022)

WARNING:tensorflow:tpu_model (from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu.keras_support) is experimental and may change or be removed at any time, and without warning.

W0605 10:36:17.816158 140062933383040 experimental.py:63] tpu_model (from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu.keras_support) is experimental and may change or be removed at any time, and without warning.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1333     try:
-> 1334       return fn(*args)
   1335     except errors.OpError as e:

10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1318       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(
-> 1319           options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1320 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1406         self._session, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1407         run_metadata)
   1408 

InvalidArgumentError: In ReadVariableOp the following variables were found uninitialized: bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/beta, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/gamma, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/position_embeddings, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/token_type_embeddings, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/dense/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/dense/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/key/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/key/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/query/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/query/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/value/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/value/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/intermediate/dense/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/intermediate/dense/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/LayerNorm/beta, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/LayerNorm/gamma, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/dense/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/dense/kernel, bert_layer_12_m...
     [[{{node ReadVariables_14728137872467799544/_1}}]]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-40-fdb59f59a0ef> in <module>()
     82       print("-----------------------------5")
     83       tpu_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model,
---> 84                                                     strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu_address)))
     85 
     86       print("-----------------------------6")

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/framework/python/framework/experimental.py in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
     62         'any time, and without warning.',
     63         decorator_utils.get_qualified_name(func), func.__module__)
---> 64     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     65   new_func.__doc__ = _add_experimental_function_notice_to_docstring(
     66       func.__doc__)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/keras_support.py in tpu_model(model, strategy)
   2219     else:
   2220       optimizer_config = None
-> 2221     model_weights = model.get_weights()
   2222   else:
   2223     model_weights = None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py in get_weights(self)
    390     for layer in self.layers:
    391       weights += layer.weights
--> 392     return backend.batch_get_value(weights)
    393 
    394   def set_weights(self, weights):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in batch_get_value(tensors)
   2817     raise RuntimeError('Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function.')
   2818   if tensors:
-> 2819     return get_session().run(tensors)
   2820   else:
   2821     return []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    927     try:
    928       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 929                          run_metadata_ptr)
    930       if run_metadata:
    931         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1150     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1151       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1152                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1153     else:
   1154       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1326     if handle is None:
   1327       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1328                            run_metadata)
   1329     else:
   1330       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1346           pass
   1347       message = error_interpolation.interpolate(message, self._graph)
-> 1348       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1349 
   1350   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: In ReadVariableOp the following variables were found uninitialized: bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/beta, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/gamma, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/position_embeddings, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/token_type_embeddings, bert_layer_12_module/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/dense/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/output/dense/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/key/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/key/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/query/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/query/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/value/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/attention/self/value/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/intermediate/dense/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/intermediate/dense/kernel, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/LayerNorm/beta, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/LayerNorm/gamma, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/dense/bias, bert_layer_12_module/bert/encoder/layer_0/output/dense/kernel, bert_layer_12_m...
     [[{{node ReadVariables_14728137872467799544/_1}}]]
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: The print("---i") tags are for debugging !!!

Comment: you got any solution. I am facing same issue

Comment: @Prady_venom: Tried reproducing your error, but when trying to run with GPU Colab Runtime, it is resulting in the Error, `NameError: name 'bert_path' is not defined`. Can you please provide complete reproducible code so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of TensorFlow Hub support creating a [Keras layer directly](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/api_docs/python/hub/KerasLayer), which makes this task much easier. The one caveat is that you must have a writable [Google Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) to cache the BERT files, since Cloud TPUs don't have access to a local file system. You can set the `TFHUB_CACHE_DIR` environment variable to point to that bucket.

Your updated code should look something like this:

```py
# Login with your Google Cloud account
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

# TensorFlow 2.2 in my case
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_gcs_config

# TODO: set these to the names of your project and bucket
!gcloud config set project YOUR-PROJECT
os.environ['TFHUB_CACHE_DIR'] = os.path.join('gs://YOUR_BUCKET/_tfhub_cache')

resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(resolver)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(resolver)
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(resolver)

# Set up GCS access with the TPU
tensorflow_gcs_config.configure_gcs_from_colab_auth()

# Your choices here
max_seq_length = 128
dropout_rate = .1
lr = .001
batch_size = 64
epochs = 10
fake_dataset_size = 2048

with strategy.scope():
  input_word_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                        name="input_word_ids")
  input_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                    name="input_mask")
  segment_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), dtype=tf.int32,
                                      name="segment_ids")
  bert_inputs = [input_word_ids, input_mask, segment_ids]
  bert_layer = hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2", trainable=True)
  pooled_output, _ = bert_layer(bert_inputs)

  step=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.1)(pooled_output)
  step=tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(step)
  step=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)(step)
  step=tf.keras.layers.Dense(256,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')(step)
  step=tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=dropout_rate)(step)

  pred=tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(step)

  model=tf.keras.Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.summary()

# Replace this with your real dataset
fake_inputs = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
    tf.ones([fake_dataset_size, max_seq_length], dtype=tf.int32),
    tf.ones([fake_dataset_size, max_seq_length], dtype=tf.int32),
    tf.zeros([fake_dataset_size, max_seq_length], dtype=tf.int32),
))
fake_labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.ones(fake_dataset_size, dtype=tf.int32)
)
fake_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((fake_inputs, fake_labels)).repeat(epochs).batch(64, drop_remainder=True)

model.fit(fake_dataset)
```

I used a fake dataset of ones and zeros to show that the model can compile and run without crashing. In practice, you'll need to preprocess your data to match the pretraining data format. See the documentation for [this BERT model](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/2) for more detailed instructions. I arbitrarily chose one of the pre-trained BERTs from TFHub for this example. See the full collection of TensorFlow 2.x BERTs [here](https://tfhub.dev/google/collections/bert/1).